# Why does log4net use transactions by default for the AdoNetAppender

Tags: sql, ado.net, log4net

I can't think of why you would ever want to use transactions when logging using log4net.  Say you have 200 log messages and the transaction fails when inserting the 150th message and rolls back.  You now have no log messages in the DB whereas if you weren't using transactions you would have 150.  Isn't it better to have some messages than none when it comes to logging?

Can anyone think of a good reason to use transactions when writing log messages to the database using log4net (assuming that you don't override the AdoNetAppender behaviour and that messages are written to the DB one row at a time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it better to have some messages than none when it comes to logging?

Yes, but log4net was not designed for [reliability](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#reliability) and I would think there is bound to be some performance hit about creating and committing 200 sql transactions as opposed to just one. I'm guessing this performance hit must be significant enough for the default to be set this way.

Comment: Yes - which is exactly why I'm wondering why the AdoNetAppender uses transactions by default.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are agreeing or disagreeing with me. The default is faster and places a lighter load on your sql server - isn't that a good enough reason for it to be the default.

Comment: I'm saying that it shouldn't use transactions at all.

Comment: But the transaction **has** to be created somewhere. If log4net does not create an explicit sql transaction, then the sql server will create an implicit sql transaction for every update/insert statement, ie 200 of them.

Comment: How naive I was in thinking that I wasn't using transactions.  This prompted me to do some performance testing and it's almnost twice as fast with transactions turned on.

**"Autocommit mode is the default transaction management mode of SQL Server Compact. Every SQL statement is committed or rolled back when it finishes. A SQL Server Compact connection operates in autocommit mode whenever this default mode has not been overridden by explicit transactions. Autocommit mode is also the default mode for ADO.NET and OLE DB."**

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172353.aspx)